# Explanation of the &error (NSError) construct in Objective-C (Use of undelcared identifier 'error')

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nserror

I am new to iOS development, and I am working on an app similar to Instagram in order to teach me the basics. I am working my way through the [AnyPic Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic) via [parse.com](https://parse.com/) because it has been useful, but in the AppDelegate.m, there is a function where the code makes a request to parse for some facebook data, and returns some data. My question is with the following lines of code:

```
PFQuery *facebookFriendsQuery = [PFUser query];
[facebookFriendsQuery whereKey:kPA_UserFacebookIDKey containedIn:facebookIds];

NSArray *facebookFriends = [facebookFriendsQuery findObjects:&error];

// This if statement gives me the following error: 
// "use of undeclared identifier 'error'"       
if (!error){ }
```

This construct:

```
NSArray *facebookFriends = [facebookFriendsQuery findObjects:&error];

if (!error){ }
```

seem straightforward enough, but it gives me an error in my code (Use of undeclared identifier 'error') but gets by without a warning in the AnyPic files.

So can someone explain what this construct is (&error), and perhaps why I might be getting this 'undeclared identifier' error?

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ //
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ //

**EDIT (Sep 14 2014): Because this post is entitled "Explanation of the &error (NSError) construct in Objective-C", I thought I would actually explain the things I have learned, in case it might help someone else in the future.** Seems silly to me now that all I was missing was the `error` variable declaration, and the `if (!error) {}` was evaluating whether or not the error variable was nil or non-nil, but the confusion seemed warranted, because in PHP, a language I am very familiar with, it is possible to assign a non-existent variable from inside a function call, and hoist it to the scope of the function that called it. For example:

```
// In PHP 

preg_match_all("/myregex/", $someString, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    // pregmatch has found some matches, and now there is a variable
    // named $matches available to the same scope where preg_match_all was called
}
```

So when I saw something similar (but not syntactically-identical) in Objective-C:

```
// In Objective-C

NSArray *myArray = [self getObjects:&error];
if(!error) {
    // This is a compiler error, because the error variable
    // doesn't exist at this point, because Objective-C won't 
    // let you assign variables in this way
}
```

So the solution is to remember, that PHP and Objective-C are very different, and **the correct syntax for using the `&` operator to cast a value (pass by reference) to a variable is like this:**

```
// In Objective-C

NSError *error = nil; // <-- THIS IS EXTREMELY IMPORTANT!
NSArray *myArray = [self getObjects:&error];
    if(!error) {
        // Now the compiler won't complain, because the error variable 
        // has been assigned. This block of code will run if the error variable
        // is still equal to nil. Which means the [self getObjects:] ran without error.
    } else {
        // if error == YES, it means that the [self getObjects:] function
        // encountered an error and has assigned the reference to the error into 
        // the error variable you previously assigned to nil, allowing it to 
        // evaluate as non-nil
    }
```

Hope this might help someone that encountered the same confusion as me.

Comment: please declare bool error before you use it upper contain &error line

Comment: @HuyNghia - It's not a `bool`.  `error` should be declared as an `NSError*`.

Comment: Every variable has to be declared.  This is one of the first things you should have learned.

Comment: ahh.@HotLicks sorry, my mistake

Comment: Yes, I know that all variables must be declared, which is obvious, but in some languages, like php and javascript, you can instantiate a variable within a statement like this: `preg_match_all("/regex/", $string, $matches);` where `$matches` is suddenly available outside of the statement. I thought the same thing could be happening here, since all I saw was a very similar construct, only related to NSErrors.

Comment: Well, you're not in PHP anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the variable `error` is not defined.

AppDelegate.m starting on line 459 you will find the error variable declared.  Then that error is changed in the event of an error on line 472.  Then on line 474 the condition checks that variable to determine if everything is ok and moves on.

```
NSError *error = nil; //line 459

NSArray *anypicFriends = [query findObjects:&error]; //line 472

if (!error) { }  // line 474
```

Comment: aha! That was it. I had missed the `NSError *error = nil;` declaration in the tutorial. Thanks!